# Magento: category layout issue

Tags: xml, magento, layout

I was trying to remove the 'compared products' and the 'viewed products' blocks on the right hand side of the category page. I removed the following 2 lines in reports.xml:

```
<block type="reports/product_viewed"  name="right.reports.product.viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml" />
        <block type="reports/product_compared"  name="right.reports.product.compared" template="reports/product_compared.phtml" />2
```

and the following line in catalog.xml:

```
<!--   <block type="core/template" name="right.permanent.callout" template="callouts/right_col.phtml"> -->
```

Now, none of my products are displayed, and whatever the link I click, it gets me to a page called 'Create new customer account' with the correct URL and an almost empty page. The header and the footer are still here as well as some of the right hand side blocks but everything in between disappeared.

I thought it would be an easy operation, so I did it straight on live site.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you rollback all your changes, and now remove the block in the correct handle.

> **Handle**: A element to differ one url to another.

All blocks are involve in handle tag in layout, and in your case you should remove the block only for the handle catalog_category_view.

And then you can put the next lines in your local.xml of your design package.

```
<catalog_category_view>
    <reference name="right">
       <remove name="right.reports.product.viewed"/>
       <remove name="right.reports.product.compared"/>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_view>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I have rolledback the site and got the layout back so no more emergency.. I tried to put these lines in the local.xml. Tried to locate it in frontend>default >mytheme and on frontend>base>default but it won't make these things disappear in any of them. Not sure what's wrong...

Comment: You should to be sure that you are editing the correct file, If you active Developer Mode and drop '<' to break the format in local.xml , Magento shows a error for you